# BigQuery Error : Bad routine reference "OFFSET" on a view of ga_realtime_sessions

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a view named "ga_realtime_view" in standard SQL from the table ga_realtime_sessions populated by Google Analytics, based on this thread:

[change view ga_realtime_sessions_view_YYYYMMDD to standard sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997359/change-view-ga-realtime-sessions-view-yyyymmdd-to-standard-sql?rq=1)

This view is based on the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS suffix,
  ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY exportTimeUsec DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.ga_realtime_sessions_20*` AS t
GROUP BY suffix, t.visitKey
```

I've been querying this view for a few months without any issue, however today it became unstable. My query sometimes gets the error:

```
Error: Bad routine reference "OFFSET"; routine references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs.
```

Sometimes I get this error when I hit "Run" and the query doesn't run.
Sometimes I hit "Run", the query runs fine until the end and I get the error when I get the results.

My query:

```sql
SELECT "France" as country,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AT TIME ZONE "Europe/Paris") AS hour,
SUM(totals.visits) as sessions,
SUM(totals.transactions) as transactions
FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.ga_realtime_view` 
GROUP BY hour
ORDER BY hour
```

I don't understand what's going on, does anyone have any idea ?
Thank you

Comment: see [Error: Bad routine reference “OFFSET”; routine references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51879715/5221944)

Comment: use [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100182)

Comment: thanks @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: see posted issues on Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692347 ; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692348 ; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112688907