# Error: Bad routine reference "OFFSET"; routine references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs

Tags: google-bigquery

We have some views/queries saved in BigQuery project which gets pulled by our BI tool. Those views haven't changed for a while and this morning we saw intermittent errors below. It doesn't occur all the time. Sometimes, the same queries were able to compile and others not.

`Error: Bad routine reference "OFFSET"; routine references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs.`

Comment: use [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1100182)

Comment: see posted issues on Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692347 ; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692348 ; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112688907

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant

Answer (score 0):

Google has fixed the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112692348

I was able to run queries this morning using ordinal and offset with no issues.